# Why does the compiler not automatically remove branches?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, optimization

I was curious about whether the compiler automatically removed branches when it could so I set up an easy case:

```
bool testConditionsIf(int i, int j) {
    if (i == 1){
        if (j == 2){
            return true;
        }
        return j == 3;
    }
    return  j == 4;
}

bool testConditionsTernary(int i, int j) {
    return i == 1 ? (j == 2 ? true : j == 3) : j == 4;
}

bool testConditionsNoBranch(int i, int j) {
    return (i == 1 && (j == 2 || j == 3)) || (i != 1 && j == 4);
}
```

Each function is semantically equivalent to the next. The second rewrites the first with ternaries instead of if statements. The third rewrites the second by using boolean logic to handle both sides of the if statement. Interestingly enough, with gcc the first two produce the same code, but the third does not. The first two are assembled with conditional checks and jumps, much like the code is written. The third has a single conditional check on 1 and then returns the boolean computation of each branch. So I have a few questions:

1. Why was a condition check + jump inserted into the third function when that is known to be a CPU slowdown?
2. Why dont all three compile to the same thing?
3. What is stopping the compiler from compiling the first two to the third?
4. The byte code for the first two does a condition check for j == 4 before doing a condition check for i == 1, why? Doesnt that seem like wasted work if i == 1?
5. If the compiler does a check for i == 1 before the jump, why is it doing that check again after the jump?
6. Why does testConditionsNoBranch have branches in it with -O0 optimization flag? The code has no branches in it as written.

https://www.godbolt.org/z/P69TGMsja

Comment: There is no requirement that compilers reduce equivalent code to identical assembly output. If you want to study the details, you'll have to look into the compiler's implementation, see which optimizations kick in and how they affect each other.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but with how impactful branching is on performance, I wouldve thought that there is a lot of free performance left on the table if this isnt being done. But generally I assume compiler writers are smarter than me, so I assume that theres some reason this transformation isnt possible and I'm just unaware. So I want to know how to write code to get optimized correctly. I do think I should expect  testConditionsNoBranch to be assembled without branches in the byte code when I turn off optimizations though, so that is baffling.

Comment: It is often the case that the way to get the optimizer to do the best job is to write the simplest code. Compiler authors probably spend more time improving optimization of "if" statements than complex boolean expressions. Note that version 2 easily transforms to version 1. But version 3 is harder to convert to the other two versions - you have to do more boolean algebra to get there.

Comment: Thats what we're talking about here: the original code is about optimizing "if" statements. The optimization is to remove the "if" because that results in faster code.

Comment: OR implies "branching". My compiler is different, and I don't often go into the assembler. A "branchless" version: `int x = (i == 1); return x*(j == 2) + x*(j == 3) + !x*(j == 4);` Give that a try.

Comment: As someone who has dabbled in writing optimizing (toy) compilers I can testify that it's a lot easier to spot an inefficiency in the generated code than it is to write a suitable fix for the optimizer, which does not have any adverse side effects.

Comment: In certain cases, branches are _faster_ than the "branchless" code. The compiler will often know/choose the more efficient sequence. I've seen code that an author, using ternary operators only swear it was branchless, but the compiler thought otherwise. In some H/W (e.g. x86), there is a branch prediction unit, and the code path taken is "speculatively" executed. That is, instructions are queued out-of-order, and the pipeline only stalls/retries if the prediction turns out to be wrong.

Comment: The short answer:  because the compiler is not required to do the code transformations you describe.   The reason it is not required is the relative efficiency of your code samples will be platform (host hardware, instruction set. etc) dependent.   Some compilers *might* (depending on optimisation settings) do such transformations.      Such things are a *quality of implementation* concern - different vendors compete by offering different qualities in their compilers, and do so differently based on what works on chosen target platforms.

Comment: A lot here also comes down to fulfilling user's expectations. Even when allowed by the standard, (some) users can and do get upset when the compiler does things they don't expect.

Comment: Clang do generate a branchless code (and it is quite efficient) especially when the code do not use the lazy operators: https://www.godbolt.org/z/3GcY4enfG . GCC generate a good code only for the last case with non-lazy operators: https://www.godbolt.org/z/nj8M1c6rP . Put it shortly: use the binary operators in this case and not the lazy ones.

Comment: After coffee: `i = (i == 1); return i&((j == 2) | (j == 3)) | !i&(j == 4);` "Branchless" #2 with explicit Boolean operators instead of arithmetic (and no temporary variable.)

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator is the same as `if` (resulting compiled code wise) and the code generated can contain branches.

> it with -O0 optimization flag

Testing code quality with optimizations disabled makes no sense.

You need to convert it into an arithmetic expression which is very likely to be compiled without any branches.

```
bool testConditionsNoBranch1(int i, int j) {
    return (i == 1) * (j == 2) + (i == 1) * (j == 3) + (i != 1) * (j == 4);
}
```

and it will be compiled (using -Ofast) to

```
testConditionsNoBranch1(int, int):
        cmp     edi, 1
        sete    cl
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     esi, 2
        sete    al
        xor     edx, edx
        and     eax, ecx
        cmp     esi, 3
        sete    dl
        and     edx, ecx
        add     eax, edx
        cmp     edi, 1
        setne   cl
        xor     edx, edx
        cmp     esi, 4
        sete    dl
        and     edx, ecx
        add     eax, edx
        setne   al
        ret
```

Comment: This code is less efficient than using the binary operator instead of the lazy ones (see my above comment). It is also less readable. I do not think this is a good idea to use it in this case for both Clang and GCC.

Comment: @JérômeRichard even that it less efficient than the branch code. And it was my point. Compilers compile it right., Branchless code is less efficient than with branches

Comment: @PeteBecker The question is about output code, not about the language. Compiled code wise they are usually identical .

Comment: @0___________ *"Branchless code is less efficient than with branches"* this is *not true* in general nor here. Branch can be expensive when they cannot be predicted (eg. dependent of the input). Anyway, this was not my point: my point was that this branchless code is slower than the one using binary operator (and less readable). What is the point of writing slower and less-readable code? (as you said: *"testing code quality with optimizations disabled makes no sense"*).

Comment: @0___________ — you seem to have mis-attributed that quote.

Comment: Note that `*` is pretty inefficient -- better to use `&` and `|` (the bitwise operators) rather than `&&` and `||` (which imply short-circuiting, so require branches)

Comment: @0___________ — I’ve deleted my comment, since your subsequent edit fixed the problem.

Comment: I think the two of you need to define "efficient", i think you two are "talking past each other", as the saying goes.

Answer (score 0):

I can certainly take a stab at some of these

> 1. Why was a condition check + jump inserted into the third function when that is known to be a CPU slowdown?

This one I can't answer.

> 2. Why dont all three compile to the same thing?

This one is simple enough. The compilers are written by different people/teams, they have to follow the standard, but the standard allows some room for interpretation (for instance, GCC and Clang disagree on scope resolution if memory serves), and then there are limitations on what the compilers can do because of how they are written. While they all work in the same basic way, the implementations are quite different.
Or to put it shortly, they differ because they are different.

> 3. What is stopping the compiler from compiling the first two to the third?

Missed optimization opportunities?
Maybe missing optimizations?
Its also possible the compilers considered the 3rd and decided against it.
Clang offers great debugging info on its optimization passes, and that would be the first place i would look.

> 4. The byte code for the first two does a condition check for j == 4 before doing a condition check for i == 1, why? Doesnt that seem like
>    wasted work if i == 1?

Obviously this is speculation, but the compiler is probably assuming `i != 1`. It *is* an int, Afterall. It has a 1 in 4,294,967,295 chance of being 1.

> 5. If the compiler does a check for i == 1 before the jump, why is it doing that check again after the jump?

After the jump its actually checking for 3. Its just coincidence that `3 - 2 == 1`

> 6. Why does testConditionsNoBranch have branches in it with -O0 optimization flag? The code has no branches in it as written.

Logical operators (`||` and `&&`) requires evaluating multiple conditions.

```
bool b = (i == 1 && j ==2)
```

is semantically the same as

```
bool b = false;
if (i == 1)
    if (j == 2)
        b = true;
```